# Explicit computation in Derived McKay Correspondence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Consider the standard action of $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$, the resulting quotient $\mathbb{C}^2/G$ is a singular variety $Spec(\mathbb{C}[x^2,xy,y^2])$. It is known that there is a commutative diagram,

\begin{array}
&Z&\xrightarrow{p} &\mathbb{C}^2&\\
\downarrow{f}&&\downarrow{\pi}\\
Y&\xrightarrow{\tau} &\mathbb{C}^2/G&
\end{array}
Here Z is the blow up of $\mathbb{C}^2$ at (0,0) and Y is the blow up of $\mathbb{C}^2/G$ at $(0,0)$.

One can check by hand that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\otimes\rho_0$,$\mathbb{C}[x,y]\otimes\rho_1$ form a set of generators of the triangulated category $D^b_G(\mathbb{C}^2)$.(the $\rho$'s are irreducible representations of $G$.)
By results of Bridgeland, King and Reid, we know that $Rp_*f^*:D^b(Y)\rightarrow D^b_G(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is an equivalence.

My question is: can one explicitly construct a object of $D^b(Y)$ whose image under the above functor is $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\otimes\rho_1$.(one can find similar thing for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\otimes\rho_0$ easily, namely $\mathcal{O}_Y$, but the $\rho_1$ part is really causing problems in our case.)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If a functor is an equivalence, its adjoint functor is its inverse. So, just apply $Rf_*p^!$ (this is the right adjoint).